# Android App unable to create directory on server

Tags: php, android, rest

I have an app that is supposed to create a directory on a server via a url. When I enter that URL into a web browser, it works. But when I register through my app, nothing appears. I have tried this with another file server and it worked. My file has a 777 permission and still nothing on the phone side. Please help

This is my php code

```
$gcmRegID  = $_POST["regID"]; 
            $gcmUserName  = $_POST["userName"]; 
            $gcmFolderName = $_POST["folderName"];

            $gcmDate = date("d/m/y");

            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            if($conn->connect_error){
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
            $in_user = "user";
            $in_password = "NULL";
            $in_email = "NULL";
            $in_dob = "NULL";
            $in_role = "user";
            $in_datejoined = "0000-00-00";

            $sql = "INSERT INTO user(password,regid,name,email,phone,dob,role,datejoined) VALUES('$in_password','$gcmRegID','$gcmUserName','$in_email','$in_phone','$in_dob','$in_role','$gcmDate')";

            //$gcmtest = "APA91bHUYXD_X2meMxOJ4JkWGyJVwv0Hy6UPvZ-5i42jLDoU3ofdEutPJspCuNDrxg-VutIHtfvDc8WSTziMxIwIh4YIZYzQiORoGG8VcV9R8azPTEXzRUkBMiKvGHXpOBJINljZyzSu";
            $substringtitle = substr($gcmRegID,-7);
            $combined = $gcmUserName."_".$substringtitle;
            if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
                //if(is_dir("users/".$gcmFolderName)===false){
                    mkdir("./users/".$gcmFolderName);
                    //echo "Folder created!";
                //}
                echo "New record created successfully";

            }else{
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
            $conn->close();

            //echo $gcmRegID;
            //file_put_contents("./GCMRegId.txt",$gcmRegID);
            echo "Done!";
            exit;
```

Comment: it seems that you have problem in your android code can you post that code here?

Comment: My android code works fine for other servers though? I'll post it up in abit.